# What phrase or verb do you use to say that someone accidentally has left a pen or marker mark on their face?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

What phrase or verb do you use to say that someone accidentally has left a pen or marker mark on their face? Which one of the following communiate the idea the best?

> You marked your face with the pen.
>
> You stained your face with the pen.
>
> You messed your face with the pen.

I feel that none sounds natural, but I cannot think of a natural way to say that. What would a native English speaker say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, unless I saw the person do it, I would simply say:

> You have some ink on your face

or (and I imagine this is possibly just an Eng(UK) way of saying it):

> You have pen on your face

.

If I did actually see somebody do it, I'd probably let them know by saying:

> You've accidentally drawn on your face

Answer (score 0):

You've got a... There is... You seem to have a... (a smudge, a little something, whatever).

It is often polite to just let your sentence trail off at the dots.